# Why background images from "public" folder in a React project do not resize according to window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

when I have a React project and want to add fullscreen backgrounds to my pages, I use this code below ([css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/))

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My problem is, if my images are in the "public" folder, they do not resize when the window is bigger or smaller. If my images are in the src/css folder, they do resize. So why is that happening? Do I have to keep my images in src folder all the time? Does it cause any problems later?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
background-size: 100% 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is related to directory of image or image path. I have checked your CSS code. I think as you already defining background-size:cover, you don't need to add "fixed" on background. Please try below code:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```